# 2004 Chrysler Concorde LX Coolant Leak

Tags: coolant, leak, chrysler, concorde

My had a slow coolant leak in his 2004 Chrysler Concorde LX. The car began to overheat & smoke from under the hood. He waited 1 1/2 hrs and added coolant.
After driving 25 minutes he parked & turned car off. When he restarted about 3-5 minutes later, the was a large leak of coolant near the rear of the car by the firewall.
What would cause this? Can we add coolant & drive it to an auto shop?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: I don't think this question can be answered here with certainty. If the shop is a 2-minute drive, it will probably be OK. If an hour, probably not. The main issue is we don't know if the engine block is completely filled with coolant or not. If it is not, severe engine damage can result from driving a long distance. Some vehicles have a step by step procedure to completely fill the engine block when coolant has been drained. Towing is the safest bet; driving the vehicle more than briefly at this point is risky.

Comment: Thank you for the response. My son had his Auto teachers cell number from when the Skills USA Team went to convention. Wednesday he is going to bring diagnostic tools & go with us.